# AM/PM отображение времени

Tags: c#, .net, время

Как сделать чтобы текущее время, например, **19:32** отображалось в формате **7:32**?

**UPD**

Вот набросок:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  Timer timer1 = new Timer();
  timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_tick);
  timer1.Interval = 100; 
  timer1.Start(); 
} 

public void timer1_tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
  DateTime ThToday = DateTime.Now; 
  string ThData = ThToday.ToString(); 
  this.label1.Text = ThData; 
}
```

Comment: А код с вашими набросками где? И как понять "переводилось" ?

Comment: С какой частью задачи у вас затруднения? Непонятно ничего или есть какой-никакой задел по задаче?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных целей используется [форматирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

К примеру у нас есть:

```
var time = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(time);
```

На выходе у нас будет:

```
16.05.2018 21:44:39
```

К примеру мы хотим изменить время, что нам следует сделать? А все просто, задать формат, некий вид того, что мы хотим видеть:

```
Console.WriteLine(time.ToString("MM.dd.yy Hч mm минут"));
```

То есть мы задали обычным string то, что хотим видеть:

- **MM.dd.yy** - дата (MM - Месяц, в диапазоне от 01 до 12; dd - День месяца, в диапазоне от 01 до 31; yy - Год, в диапазоне от 00 до 99.).
- **H** - Час в 24-часовом формате от 0 до 23. + дописали букву "ч".
- **mm** - Минуты, в диапазоне от 00 до 59. + дописали слово "минуты".

Вывод:

```
05.16.18 21ч 47 минут
```

Comment: Человеку нужен как раз таки 12-часовой формат.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Ну я указал ссылку на полную таблицу всех форматов. Как нужно человеку - решать ему, я лишь написал пример того, что можно сделать.